# creating a dynamic constraint layout

Tags: android

I'm devising a multi file processing system, and they have an interface like this:

[image: file processing system]

**The lime arrows show the constraint setup, and the orange box holding the widget is a constrain layout**

So, I'd like to make this constraint layout dynamic say I'm only processing 1 file then only a button and its corresponding progress bar should appear, if two files are being processed then 2 buttons and 2 corresponding progress bar should appear and the (orange) constraint layout should resize as well.

For this type of appearing of a group of widgets (the button and it's corresponding progress bar) it seems sensible to save them in a layout and reuse them using `<include>`, but then the sizes look dynamic that I think the whole UI thing could be just done in java.

So, I'm confused to how to go about making this sort of UI design. The questions that arise would be:

1) If I save the button and it's corresponding progress bar as a layout, how do I reuse it, like I'd have to instantiate it every time no. of file processed would change, setup their constraint, provide different ID to each button and progress bar. (If not possible to answer all these, please tell me if it's at least possible using xml layout to do this)

2) Just use plain java code for all the UI designs that relate to the constraint layout. The code and UI would not be separate.(I think this is how to handle this sort of thing, but, I'm not very knowledged)

So, what would be the appropriate way to go about doing this.

Comment: I would suggest to go with **LinearLayout with vertical orientation**. Why? Constraints usually added up by giving ids  as reference constraints to [top, bottom, left & right]. So, according to your need it would require more efforts and complex logic to build such thing compared to LinearLayout programmatically.

Comment: so, this sort of dynamic thing should be done programmatically? Rather than using xml?

Comment: but, when the device is rotated or different devices are used, wouldn't linear layout like distort the positions of buttons or something?

Comment: Why not create one constraint layout (so you're getting all the benefits of constraints vs Linear layouts) as part of a recycler view, and dynamically add or remove items using the view's adapter.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo , didn't know much about recycler view, I'll try to research on this. Just a side question though... does it allow adding elements with database?

Comment: It sure does! This id the developer's guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview but there are also plenty of examples for recycler views on Stack Overflow.